# How do I reduce bounding box shake/jitter in YOLO?

Tags: lstm, bounding-box, yolo, jitter

Is there any way to get less jitter on bounding boxes? I sort of understand [why they happen](http://cs230.stanford.edu/projects_winter_2019/reports/15812427.pdf).

And I am not the only one seeing this. See the video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vGiHciI-NC0).

But I don't see any patches or fixes for this behavior. It also seems to happen within SSDs. From that paper, it seems like the solution is to pass information from one frame to the next... but I haven't been able to find any implementations of this yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [object tracking](https://cv-tricks.com/object-tracking/quick-guide-mdnet-goturn-rolo/). It ensures stability along with more efficient use of computational resources also.

If you are into research, [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.06467.pdf) might give you a better idea.